# IF short syntax in c

Tags: c, ternary-operator, conditional-operator

i know that if can be writen in short way syntax in c
please show me how

```
   if arraeck(a, n) ?    printf("YES")    printf("NO");
```

some thing like this?..in one line...
What is the correct syntax
?

Comment: Do you mean the `?:` operator? Its syntax is _condition_ ? _expression_if_true_ : _expression_if_false_.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Direct translation of your sample code:

```
 arraeck(a, n) ? printf("YES") : printf("NO");
```

Or even shorter:

```
 printf(arraeck(a, n) ? "YES" : "NO");
```

This is called the [(ternary) conditional operator `?:`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:) and it's not always the best solution to use it, as it can be hard to read. You usually only use it if you need the result of the conditional, like in the second code sample (the operator evaluates to `"YES"` or `"NO"` here).

In the first sample, the operator is not used as an an expression, so you should better use an explicit `if` (it's not that long after all):

```
if (arraeck(a, n))
    printf("YES");
else
    printf("NO");
```

Answer (score 12):

```
if (cond) {
    exp1;
} else {
    exp2;
}
```

Can be written as

```
cond ? exp1 : exp2;
```

This form is commonly used for conditional assignment like this (from [Wikipedia entry of ?:](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F%3a)):

```
variable = condition ? value_if_true : value_if_false
```

Answer (score 9):

`?:` is not equivalent to `if`: the latter is a statement, but the former is an expression.

You can do:

```
arraeck(a, n) ? printf("YES") : printf("NO");
```

but it is bad style.

You can also do

```
str = arraeck(a, n) ? "YES" : "NO";
printf(arraeck(a, n) ? "YES" : "NO");
```

but you can't write

```
str = if (arraeck(a, n)) "YES"; else "NO";
printf(if (arraeck(a, n)) "YES"; else "NO");
```

Answer (score 3):

```
printf(arraeck(a,n) ? "YES" : "NO");
```