# Program to input correct password and limiting to tries

Tags: c, loops

I am attempting to solve this coding question where the password has been set, and compare the user's input with the password. If the password matches, program outputs correct, if it doesnt, user has three maximum tries to fill in the correct password.

The program works fine but i noticed one small issue, if the tries < 3, the loop is never exited and it will be incomplete. This is the program i coded.

```
void matching(int matches)
    {
         if(matches == 0)
         {
             printf("You have entered the correct password!\n");
         }
    }

int main()
{
    char password[]= "tacobell";
    char input[15];
    int match;
    int count = 0;

    printf("Enter your password here: ");
    scanf("%s", input);

    match = strcmp(password, input);
    matching(match);

        while(match != 0)
    {
        while (count<3)
        {
            if (match != 0){
            printf("You have entered the wrong password, try again: ");
            scanf("%s", input);`enter code here`
            count++;
            match = strcmp(password, input);
            match = matching(match);
              //exits the while loop once the password has matched where match takes 0 value
        }
        }

        printf("You have attempted to log in %d times. ", count); //total number of scans will be returned
        printf("You have run out of tries, please try again later. \n");
        break;

    }

}
```

Comment: `match = matching(match);` quick question, what do you think this is doing?

Comment: You need to **salt and hash** the stored password. **Do not store the password in plain-text anywhere.** When someone tries to login you use the same salt and hashing algorithm on the attempted password, and then compare the hashes rather than comparing to the password directly. Anything less is **WRONG**, and password handling is one of a small number of things too important to do wrong, even in learning and proof of concept projects.

Comment: As you have it now, the only way you can break out of your inner while loop is on the `count` value. But your count increment is within a conditional statement. Is there a condition where your increment will never occur?

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn I think this is just a beginner's exercise and not real world password managing, so storing the password as plain text is perfectly OK.

Comment: @Jabberwocky I repeat: "too important to do wrong even in learning/proof of concept projects".

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn this kind of exercises is not even a proof of concept, it's just simple exercises to play around with string comparision and simple algorithms. "Salt" and "Hash" son't mean anything to beginners.that ask questions about simple problems like this.

Answer (score 0):

Recomended links:
You can find more about bit operators [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-language/c-logical-operators?view=msvc-170).
With them you can chain multiple conditions in one 
`if statement` or `while statement` etc.

I have used a short if statement in printf for example to determine if it was only one try or multiple tries and depending on this the singular form of try is printed or the plural form of try.
You can find more about short if statements [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8777851/if-short-syntax-in-c)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#pragma warning (disable:4996)
void matching(int matches)
{
    if (matches == 0)
    {
        printf("You have entered the correct password!\n");
    }
}

int main()
{
    char password[] = "tacobell";
    char input[15];
    int match;
    int count = 0;

    printf("Enter your password here: ");
    scanf("%s", input);
    count = 1;  //first attempt

    match = strcmp(password, input);
    matching(match);
    
    //I have combined your two conditions with the bit operator &&(and) it is only
    //executet as long as both are true -> if the right password is entered the second
    //condition after && 'match != 0' is no longer true and while is no longer executed
    //-> if count = 3 the left condition is false and while is no longer executed more
    //Info about bit operator && and more are in the first link
    while (count < 3 && match != 0)
    {
        printf("You have entered the wrong password, try again: ");
        scanf("%s", input);
        count++;
        match = strcmp(password, input);
    }

    //(count == 1) ? "time" : "times" is a short if statement it reads like this
    //if (count == 1){ "time" } else { "times" }
    //but you can't write if (count == 1){ "time" } else { "times" } in printf
    //more to short if statements can you find in the second link
    printf("You have attempted to log in %d %s.\n", count, (count == 1) ? "time" : "times"); //total number of scans will be returned

    //You have run out of tries should only be printed if the match wasn't found
    //an alternative to the short version would be
    //if (match != 0){ printf("You have run out of tries, please try again later. \n"); }
    //more to short if statements can you find in the second link
    printf("%s", (match != 0) ? "You have run out of tries, please try again later. \n" : "");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).